# deploy two django projects with apache2 and mod_wsgi under windows server 2016

Tags: django, windows, apache, mod-wsgi, django-wsgi

I am deploying two projects on Django, one of the two is going well but when I want to access the second, I have `NOT FOUND` on the browser

here is my wsgi.py code from the first application:

```py
import os,sys

sys.path.append('C:/Apache24/htdocs/MEKAMBO') 

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

#os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'MEKAMBO.settings')
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "MEKAMBO.settings"

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

here is my wsgi.py code for the second application:

```py
import os,sys

sys.path.append('C:/Apache24/htdocs/log_audit') 

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

#os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'log_audit.settings')
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "log_audit.settings"

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

here is the httpd.conf code:

```
LoadFile "C:/Users/HELPDESK/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python312.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "C:/Users/HELPDESK/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/Lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp312-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome C:/Apache24/htdocs/MEKAMBO/env
WSGIPythonPath C:/Apache24/htdocs/MEKAMBO

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mekambo.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/Apache24/htdocs/MEKAMBO/MEKAMBO"

    WSGIScriptAlias /mekambo "C:/Apache24/htdocs/MEKAMBO/MEKAMBO/wsgi.py"

    Alias /media/ C:/Apache24/htdocs/MEKAMBO/media/
    Alias /static/ C:/Apache24/htdocs/MEKAMBO/static/

    <Directory C:/Apache24/htdocs/MEKAMBO/static>
    Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory C:/Apache24/htdocs/MEKAMBO/media>
    Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory "C:/Apache24/htdocs/MEKAMBO/MEKAMBO">
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.log_audit.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/Apache24/htdocs/log_audit/log_audit"

    WSGIScriptAlias /log_audit "C:/Apache24/htdocs/log_audit/log_audit/wsgi.py"



    <Directory "C:/Apache24/htdocs/log_audit/log_audit">
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>`
```